# Programas escritos em Ruby funcionam tanto no Windows quanto no Linux?

Tags: ruby

É uma dúvida que eu tenho em relação a essa linguagem de programação.

O *Java*, por exemplo, não possui distinção de *SO's*, pois o mesmo possui algo parecido com um *SO* interno, por isso não precisa de um *port* específico para cada *SO*. O mesmo código funciona tanto para o Linux quanto Windows, no entanto, existem linguagens que possuem distinção, como no caso do C. Porém aprendi *Ruby* há pouco tempo, e depois de alguns testes percebi que não precisei fazer um *port* específico pro meu código rodar para cada *SO* (Windows e Linux).

- No *Ruby* não é necessário fazer *ports* específicos para um
  determinado programa rodar em cada *SO*?
- O programa funciona nos dois Sistemas (Windows e Linux)
  independente de qual você opte por desenvolver?

Agradeço a quem puder me responder.

Obs.: *SO* = Sistema Operacional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plataforma *Ruby* possui o **Ruby MRI** - A *referência de implementação* para interpretadores desta linguagem, escrito em *C*.

O repositório [oficial de testes das especificações *Ruby*](https://github.com/ruby/spec) informa que o *Ruby MRI* roda em **30 plataformas:**

> ruby/spec is known to be tested in these implementations for every
>   commit:
>
> - MRI on **30 platforms** and 4 versions
> - JRuby on Travis for both 1.7 and 9.x
> - TruffleRuby on Travis
> - Opal on Travis

Em resumo, a compatibilidade de uma aplicação *Ruby* com diferentes plataformas poderá ser quebrada caso algoritmos **interajam diretamente com funcionalidades particulares** de um *Sistema Operacional* (eg.: *Windows*, *Linux*, *MacOS*)